# How to convert a local directory into Git, compare differences with remote repository, and then commit?

Tags: git

I've erroneously written changes into a copy of a remote repository that is no longer version controlled by Git. I need to convert this local directory back into a Git repository, compare differences with the remote branch, and then commit only those changes on top as you would normally.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you know roughly which file / directory you did modified / added or is there to much changes?

Comment: Yes, there's only a few files in the entire repository.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I would see is to use `git diff` by specified the actual files who changed.

Something along the line of:

```
 git diff non_git_dir/the-files-*.js git-dir/the-files-*.js > patch.diff
```

If you have both directory on your disk and can relatively easily point the files you know have changed, it would generate a reasonably good diff file.

Then you would just have to apply the diff on you git managed directory:

```
  git apply patch.diff
```

And from there you can commit or do what you want.

---

If however the changes are to broad or you can't have the files on your disk for any reason. Maybe you can try to:

- Make your old stuff managed by Git again: `git init`
- Commit everything: `git add .` `git commit -m"ALL THE THINGS"`
- Add your remote repo: `git remote add new git@github:newrepo.git`
- And then try to generate an acceptable diff: `git diff master new/master`
- Apply the diff is probably the cleanest solution anyway, as a merge would look very suspicious on the history

---

Of course there is also the possibility to just copying the files over and check any potential code lost before committing.

But it sounds like cheating

---

My two cents...